# Problem updating in Ubuntu: E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success

Tags: 16.04, apt

I've just installed a new fresh Ubuntu 16.04. I was just going to install `simplescreenrecorder`. I added this PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder`

After running `sudo apt-get update` it returned the following:

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'

E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

`sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder` worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like appstream bug. You can purge `libappstream3` completely, but if you still need appsteam, try to comment last 3 lines in file:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

This solution doesn't fix the bug, but hides the appstream error message during apt updates disabling refresh appsteam cache when apt's cache is updated.